# Angular checkbox checked by default in template driven form

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-forms, angular-ngmodel

I have a template driven Angular form, containing a checkbox, which I want to be checked by default. Here is the minimized code:

*app.component.html:*

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(form.value)">
  <input #cb1 type="checkbox" name="cb1" ngModel checked />
  <input #cb2 type="checkbox" name="cb2" ngModel checked="true" />
  <input #cb3 type="checkbox" name="cb3" [(ngModel)]="value" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

*app.component.ts:*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
  value=true;
  submit(x: any) {
    console.log(x);
  }
}
```

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w3amnq?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

In my project, I add the checkbox to the Angular form using the syntax in the first two checkboxes, by adding the `ngModel` directive, without using two-way binding. I tried two different ways to make the checkbox checked by default, but neither worked. I only managed to make it work by using two way binding on `ngModel`, as shown in the third checkbox. Is there a way to make it work without two way binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `ngModel` - see [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xv3t2h?file=src/app/app.component.html).

**UPD:** If you would like to have that checkboxes on the form - you could use `[ngModel]="true"`. [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xv3t2h?file=src/app/app.component.html) updated.

Comment: Ok, but I still want the checkbox added to the ngForm. If I submit the form (click the button) only the value of the last checkbox is printed, in your stackblitz.

Comment: Then, you could use `[ngModel]="true"` - see [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xv3t2h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: That solves it indeed. I accepted the answer, maybe add your last comment to the original answer. Thanks :)